# Como ejecutar un archivo PHP desde cron

Tags: php, hosting, cron

Tengo alojado en [hostinger](https://www.hostinger.es/) una aplicación web. y he tratado hacer que cada día ejecute un archivo `.php` el cual contiene una consultas a la base de datos `Mysql`.

Basado en esa consulta crea nuevos registros; pero sucede que el `cron` funciona normal con ejemplos como enviar `email`; pero con el archivo que deseo no hace nada.

Pero este archivo si accedo por el navegador le doy la ruta; se ejecuta normal.

Comment: Podrías ejecutarlo directamente con php, si el intérprete está instalado... pero si está en un servidor web, podrías colocar una llamada de curl al url: `* * * * * curl http://localhost/blahblah/el-script.php` (colocando la configuracón adecuada para _cuando_ lo vas a ejecutar, en vez de los 5 *s que yo usé.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! podes agregar mas info sobre tu hosting?

Comment: El comentario de @Bryro no es pertinente en tu caso. La respuesta no ofrece solución para hosting compartidos. Si tu sitio tiene un punto de entrada como index.php puedes insertarle un pequeño bloque de validación `siHoyNoSeHaEjecutadoCron(){ hagaLoQueNecesito(); }` Creas un método de consulta a la BD para saber si ya se hizo lo que quieres y otro para invocar tu actualización

Comment: El defecto de el tipo de solución es que produce un pequeño retardo de carga para el primer usuario que llega a partir del momento propuesto para ejecución del "pseudo-cron"